# Minecraft Pi Edition Performance on Pi2 Compare to Pi1?

Tags: minecraft

I gave my son a Pi1 Model B as Christmas present back in 2014.  He likes to play Minecraft on it, but it never worked well or smooth enough on our 1080p TV.  Would "upgrading" his computer to a Pi2 provide better framerate and not crash as often?  He's fine with playing standalone, so no need to run additional server, etc.

(To be honest, I just need an excuse to buy a Pi2.)

Comment: Is he playing Minecraft (Linux edition, currently 1.8.8) on it, or Minecraft Pi edition (version 0.1.something)? Big difference between the two. For the first - I'm not sure it will ever run smoothly, even on an rPi2. The latter is made specifically for the rPi but is a REALLY old version, no mobs etc., more intended for programming purposes.

Comment: @PhilB: This seems like a good answer... Mind posting your comment as one?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on which Minecraft he is using (the title of your post says "Minecraft Pi Edition" but just making sure).
Is he playing Minecraft (Linux edition, currently 1.8.8) on it, or Minecraft Pi edition (version 0.1.something)? Big difference between the two. For the first - I'm not sure it will ever run smoothly, even on an rPi2. You typically need a multicore laptop/desktop PC to run Minecraft. The latter (Minecraft Pi Edition (aka mcpi)) is made specifically for the rPi but is a REALLY old version, no mobs etc., more intended for programming purposes. It should run fine (but of course much "finer" on rPi2's 4 cores than the rPi's single core) on either version, provided you make sure it uses the VideoCoreIV GPU (which it should use by default).

Answer (score -2):

If you are referring to running the game itself with interface and all, I would steer clear of a raspberry pi. Now i haven't tried minecraft on rpi2, but I would suggest some android TV device and attach a controller Instead. And then use the raspberry pi as a headless server instead